# Doctrine Error saving two records at once (new entity was found through the relationship)

Tags: php, symfony

When I want to save **1 record** to the database, **everything works correctly**.

When I want to save **2 records** right after each other - an **error** occurs:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException]
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\User#directory' that was not configured to cascade persist
operations for entity:. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity
or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Main\Entity\Directory#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

I just started learning symfony and can't figure out what the problem is.

In my case: I create a new user who takes certain information from a directory that is already in my database.
For example, my new user is a cat lover, then the entry "loves cats" should pull up from the directory.
The text of the error says that I have to set up a connection and save a new record about the love of cats. But my reference book is already full, it does not need to be supplemented, just take information from there.
When I create one user, everything is fine. When I create two users who are supposed to take information from the directory and save the data, an error occurs.
Help me please.

I tried in different places to use method: `$this->em->clear()`. But it did not help.

```
class User:

ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Directory")
JoinColumn(nullable=true)

private $directory;
```

```
public function createData($data) {

   $this->setData($data);

   $this->em->flush();

}
```

```
public function setData($data) {

   $user = new User();

   $directory = $this->em->getRepository(Directory::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $data['id']]);

   $user->setDirectory($directory);

   return $this;

}
```

Comment: The error says the problem lies with the Comment entity. Could you post your Comment entity?

Comment: Lots of identical questions.  You probably need cascade="persist".  Or else you did not pull your reference data from the database.

Comment: Sorry, I added the error text incorrectly. Corrected. 
The code where I request data from it is given. I call a method `$this->em->getRepository(Directory::class)->findOneBy()` and want to add data to the database.
For some reason, when saving one record, everything works, when saving two in a row - no.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure cascade operations for Directory entity which relates to user. Or you can do `$em->persist($directory)` before flushing